# После обновления появился индикатор капса в углу экрана

Tags: windows, windows-10, xiaomi

Решил всё-таки обновиться до Windows 10 20H2, вроде бы всё хорошо, но индикатор caps'a очень не нравится. Я часто нажимаю его и теперь эта иконка постоянно в углу. Посмотрев параметр, не удалось найти ничего связанного с этим. Может кто знает как это отключить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: эт точно винда, а не строннее по ?

Comment: 20Н2 или 21Н2?.

Comment: @entithat
Выпуск Windows 10 Домашняя
Версия 20H2
Дата установки ‎20.‎03.‎2021
Сборка ОС 19042.985
Взаимодействие Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.2020.0

Comment: @Интик
Вы похоже правы, ноутбук что-то установил своё вместе с обновлением винды. Пока не могу понять какой процесс за это отвечает, но этот индикатор оказался кликабельным, хоть и не по всей области.
upd. Нашёл, это OSDUtility.exe, утилита на ноутах Xiaomi.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы попали с этим вопросом сюда, то у вас ноутбук от xiaomi. При обновлении винды он скачал утилиту и установил. OSDUtility.exe, находится в Program files в папке MI, там же лежит юнинсталлер.